# Diffie-Hellman test vectors

Tags: unit-testing, cryptography, protocols, public-key, public-key-encryption

I need to do unit-testing to check that implementation of Diffie-Hellman key agreement protocol works right, so I need test vectors to validate on. The problem is that I cannot find them anywhere in internet. RFC-2631 contains test vectors but only for ZZ vector. I need test fectors for P, G, Xa etc.

Comment: what does it mean to have a test vector for P? Or G? Those are domain parameters and basically constants. Xa is just a random integer. And RFC-2631 does not really contain any useful test vectors for the exponentiation. The test data in the RFC is solely for the key expansion phase.

Comment: test vectors means data which allows you to check whether you implementation of calculations is right

Answer (score 7):

There is an enormous collection of DH test vectors maintained by the [U.S. NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/index.html) [here](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/keymgmt/kastestvectors.zip).

UPDATE:

Ok, here is one example from the file `KAS/FFC/Test of 800-56A excluding KDF/FFC Static Scheme/KASValidityTest_FFCStatic_NOKC_ZZOnly_resp.fax`

The beginning of the file has some text comments and then the following lines:

```
P = da3a8085d372437805de95b88b675122f575df976610c6a844de99f1df82a06848bf7a42f18895c97402e81118e01a00d0855d51922f434c022350861d58ddf60d65bc6941fc6064b147071a4c30426d82fc90d888f94990267c64beef8c304a4b2b26fb93724d6a9472fa16bc50c5b9b8b59afb62cfe9ea3ba042c73a6ade35
Q = f2ca7621eb250aa5f22cef1907011295defc50a7
G = a51883e9ac0539859df3d25c716437008bb4bd8ec4786eb4bc643299daef5e3e5af5863a6ac40a597b83a27583f6a658d408825105b16d31b6ed088fc623f648fd6d95e9cefcb0745763cddf564c87bcf4ba7928e74fd6a3080481f588d535e4c026b58a21e1e5ec412ff241b436043e29173f1dc6cb943c09742de989547288
```

For now, don't worry about `Q`. The `G` and `P` values have the same meaning as `g` and `p` in [RFC 2631](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2631). These values are used for the next 24 test vectors in the file. The first such vector is listed as:

```
COUNT = 0
XstatCAVS = 42c6ee70beb7465928a1efe692d2281b8f7b53d6
YstatCAVS = 5a7890f6d20ee9c7162cd84222cb0c7cb5b4f29244a58fc95327fc41045f476fb3da42fca76a1dd59222a7a7c3872d5af7d8dc254e003eccdb38f291619c51911df2b6ed67d0b459f4bc25819c0078777b9a1a24c72e7c037a3720a1edad5863ef5ac75ce816869c820859558d5721089ddbe331f55bef741396a3bbf85c6c1a
XstatIUT = 54081a8fef2127a1f22ed90440b1b09c331d0614
YstatIUT = 0b92af0468b841ea5de4ca91d895b5e922245421de57ed7a88d2de41610b208e8e233705f17b2e9eb91914bad2fa87f0a58519a7da2980bc06e7411c925a6050526bd86e621505e6f610b63fdcd9afcfaa96bd087afca44d9197cc35b559f731357a5b979250c0f3a254bb8165f5072156e3fd6f9a6e69bcf4b4578f78b3bde7
Z = 8d8f4175e16e15a42eb9099b11528af88741cc206a088971d3064bb291eda608d1600bff829624db258fd15e95d96d3e74c6be3232afe5c855b9c59681ce13b7aea9ff2b16707e4c02f0e82bf6dadf2149ac62630f6c62dea0e505e3279404da5ffd5a088e8474ae0c8726b8189cb3d2f04baffe700be849df9f91567fc2ebb8
CAVSHashZZ = eb99e77ac2272c7a2ee70c59375ac4d167312c20
Result = P (0 - Correct)
```

Don't worry too much about the labels, just know the the `XstatCAVS` and `XstatIUT` are the same as `xa` and `xb` in RFC-2631, and `YstatCAVS` and `YstatIUT` are the same as `ya` and `yb` in RFC-2631. Finally, `Z` is the same as `ZZ` in RFC-2631.

Finally, the line `Result = P` means that the values given are what you should get -- P means "passed". If you look at the next example (COUNT = 1), it has `Result = F` which means failure. Your implementation should *not* get that result if it is correct.

Comment: Thank you. But I am afraid there are only vectors for ECC DH as opposed to classical DH.

Comment: Could you provide the full path within the archive for a test sample for classic Diffie-Hellman (as described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie_hellman#Description)? Thank you.